# Why Oracle db doesn't work with as

Tags: sql, oracle

This code doesn't work in Oracle

```
SELECT cost
FROM
    (
            SELECT shoppingserviceid,cost,bsid
            FROM service JOIN shopping_service 
            ON service.serviceid = shopping_service.serviceid 
    ) as S
WHERE cost = 2000
```

But this code below works

```
SELECT cost
FROM
        (
            SELECT shoppingserviceid,cost,bsid
            FROM service JOIN shopping_service 
            ON service.serviceid = shopping_service.serviceid 
        ) 
WHERE cost = 2000
```

Well, I am new in oracle and before I am used to code in MySQL. How can I use `AS` statement in oracle?

Comment: Simple answer: you can't. Oracle chose to not support `AS` for a table alias

Comment: When you use alias on subquery to define a table you don't add AS command.

Answer (score 7):

Table aliases in Oracle don't use the `AS` keyword:

```
SELECT cost -- can also use S.cost
FROM
        (
            SELECT shoppingserviceid,cost,bsid
            FROM service JOIN shopping_service 
            ON service.serviceid = shopping_service.serviceid 
        ) S
WHERE cost = 2000 -- Can also use S.cost
```

Comment: but another question: now i put code as answer but it is not answer.